# magento 2.2.2 array_replace_recursive(): recursion detected

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.2

I have installed new magento 2.2.2 version but when i run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` getting error `Warning: array_replace_recursive(): recursion detected in vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php on line 158`

how can i solve that ?

Comment: please check following link hope will help you

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12097

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari yes i have checked this but not working for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had  the same issue but i tried with installing latest wamp an it is working fine now. It is issue with php version please upgrade php version with the latest one.

Here is my php configuration that i m using for my magento version 2.2.2

```
Apache 2.4.27
PHP 7.1.9
Mysql 5.7.19
Wamp 3.1.0
```

[Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/jLV5jXcE0XA0)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this temporary solution in magento 2.2.3 
open file: /vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php
replace `array_replace_recursive` to `@array_replace_recursive`