# Warning: array_replace_recursive(): recursion detected in /app/***/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php on line 207

Tags: magento2, store-view, multi-website

I am on Magento 2.4 (Cloud) and my problem is that I cannot create new websites/stores/store views via the admin panel.

```
Warning: array_replace_recursive(): recursion detected in /app/***/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php on line 207
```

Can somebody please help?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a supported php version? As per this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208684/magento-2-2-2-array-replace-recursive-recursion-detected

Comment: yes, 7.3 should be good